# Customize a bootstrap template for the mobile viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap based template that outputs a text with a button and an image. By checkbox you can select here that the picture appears either to the right or to the left of the text.

Now I have the problem that the text and button always appears above or below the picture in the mobile viewport. But I want the text and button to always appear below the picture.

I just can not figure out how to customize the template. Since I can not read the viewport size with PHP, I can not think of anything but JavaScript. Or is there a better and easier way?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    </section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Privatumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Büroumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Projektumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="files/theme/img/demo-image-02.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Möbelmontage</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Mitarbeiterumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="files/theme/img/demo-image-02.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Möbellogistik</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
  </body>
</html>


</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Privatumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="files/theme/img/demo-image-02.jpg" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Büroumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Projektumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Möbelmontage</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Mitarbeiterumzüge</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="leistungen" class="projects-section bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters mb-4 mb-lg-5">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" width="700" height="500" alt="Blablabla" itemprop="image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-12">
        <div class="featured-text">
          <h4>Möbellogistik</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum voluptatibus facere recusandae perspiciatis, nobis voluptates, sed quod dolorum distinctio odit tempora exercitationem corporis magni at ea, sint, in ipsam doloremque!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#kontakt" class="btn btn-primary js-scroll-trigger">Anfrage stellen!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

That's what it looks like on desktop:

[image]

And that's what it looks like on mobile. Here, I just want the text always to appear under the picture and not over it:

[image]

Comment: The whole idea of bootstrap is that you use the classes to create responsive design based on the viewport size. Also, I pity whoever has to edit this code. Why is every single line wrapped in `<?php ?>`?

Comment: Have you heard of @media queries? This is a JS/CSS issue you have not related in the slightest to Bootstap or PHP. If you add screenshots of what you have and  a picture of what you want I will write the code

Comment: @miken32 
I already know how bootstrap works because I have been working with it for several years. But I remember classes used to fix such floating things. So it could be determined with classes whether the element appears below or above another element. The PHP or the syntax belongs to an extension of the CMS Contao and was not written by me.

Comment: @CHunter Of course I have already worked with media queries, but I have not found a suitable solution for this. I updated my question and added pictures.

Comment: Can you get rid of the php code and just show the final HTML output. And fix your tags to reflect this and also which version of bootstrap you’re using.

Comment: @miken32 
I use Bootstrap 4 in the latest version. I've prepared a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JmJBWd?editors=1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the bootstrap classes `d-flex` and `flex-column-reverse`.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  // add bootstrap flex classes to :even rows if viewport is smaller then 1200px, remove otherwise
  if ($(window).width() < 1200){
    $('.services-section:even .row').addClass('d-flex flex-column-reverse');
  }else{
    $('.services-section:even .row').removeClass('d-flex flex-column-reverse');
  }
});
```